# scrollTop() still not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, scrolltop

I'm having that annoying `.scrollTop()` not working problem. I'm trying to get the page to start at the top every time you hit the refresh button. To do this I added the `$('html,body').scrollTop(0)` to the `$(document).ready`. Works fine in Firefox but not in Chrome nor Safari. The `scrollTop` function works fine throughout the page (i.e. smooth scroll links), just not when you hit refresh on the page.

I am at a loss; tried different combos: `$('html')`, `$('body')`, `$('html,body')`, `$(document)` ,`$(window)`...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('html,body').scrollTop(0);
})​;​
```

Comment: Are you on OS X? If so, have at look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13600832/149330

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830080/jquery-scrolltop-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-safari-or-chrome-windows

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need any animations, you could use the native JS function to do this instead of with jQuery. Just pass `0,0` and you'll be all right.

```
window.scrollTo(x-value, y-value);
```